# Does securelogin module needs to have a certificate?

Tags: users, security

**securelogin** seems to be a must to protect against spying login/password.

However it is not clear (to me) **whether it requires a SSL Certificate**.
I couldn't find this info neither in its module page nor anywhere else  :
http://drupal.org/project/securelogin
(is it too obvious that it does not need to say ?).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the securelogin module requires an SSL certificate. From the README file:

> Before enabling the module, you need to set up your server to support
>    23 SSL.

Comment: My reputation does not allow me to vote you up. Tx anyway.